# Cast observable<string> to string typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

On ngOnInit() I am reading the query parameters from the following code. How cast the observable to string?

```
  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute) { }

  textToDisplay: Observable<string>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.textToDisplay = this.router
      .queryParamMap
      .pipe(map(params => params.get('session_id') || 'None'));
  }
```

Comment: Just use `subscribe` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Subscribe` method. Consider the following example:

```
 this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params); // {order: "popular"}
    this.order = params.order;
    console.log(this.order); // popular
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution as given :

```
constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute) { }

  textToDisplay: Observable<string>;

  ngOnInit() {
     this.router.queryParams.subscribe(resp => {
        if (resp.status) {
          //get response data
          this.textToDisplay = resp
        }
      });
  }
```